# How to get Magento to display multiple group products from a category on one page?

Tags: php, magento, product

I am trying to get several grouped products from a category to be displayed on one page.

Would I need to create a new template for categories where the admin can select from backend whether to show default listing or the custom template. The custom template will show all group products from 1 category.

Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Comment: You are trying. So come back once you have a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter this will filter your collection and return you grouped products. Your can use this filter in app/code/core/Mage/catalog/Block/Product/List.php

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'))
->setPage(1, 10)
->addCategoryFilter($category)
->load();
```